# Por qué está redireccción wordpress no funciona?

Tags: wordpress

Estoy tratando de hacer una redirección dentro de mi plugin, lo que quiero es enviar directamente a la pagina de edición de post, pero en vez de eso, me está llevando al listado de posts.

```
wp_redirect( get_edit_post_link( $post_id ) ); exit;
```

Para su información, `get_edit_post_link()` me está retornando el valor correcto de la url: http://localhost/wp-admin/post.php?post=63&action=edit

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la referencia de Wordpress, debes utilizar un "Exit" luego de la función.

Quizá el código continúa y no realiza la redirección.

Fuente: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, se me olvidó publicarlo pero tengo un exit, lo que me parece extraño es que wordpress no mantiene la url, me reenvia a una totalmente diferente.

Comment: Ya probé con header() y un script, todas me terminan enviando a la lista de posts en vez de a la pagina de edición directamente.

Comment: Buenas Roger, quizá sea una pregunta muy básica pero, tienes algún plugin de cache?